# How to print out function pointer's value, return address of a function, and frame stack address of a function

Tags: c++

I wrote the following programs to print out function pointer's value, return address of a function, and frame stack address of a function. However, the output are unexpected. Could you please explain where I get wrong.

1. I declare function pointers that store the address of the function. I expect that function pointer would save stack memory. That is, when a function is called, instead of adding another stack frame, the function pointer allows returning to the stack frame that holds the function information.

```
int add(int, int) {  // do some logic }
int (*operationPtr)(const int, const int) = nullptr;
operationPtr = &a;
printf("operationPtr pointing to add function at address: 0x%08x \n",*operationPtr);
```

I expect that each time I call `operationPtr(5,6)` after assigning `operationPtr = &a`, the program would pop-out the top stack frame that has the calling function, and returns to the address frame of `add`. Therefore, `*operationPtr`, should print out the same address. But it doesn't.

In fact, I have a warning, `format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)(int, int)’`. Could you please explain why `*operationPtr` is not a good way to print out address of the stack frame.

2. I used `__builtin_frame_address(0)` to print out address of a function and  `__builtin_frame_address(1)` of the calling function.

I expect that when `calculate` calls `add` or `subtract`, the frame stack that holds `calculate` or `add` would pop out from the stack. Either of them has to be pop out. But in all the time that those functions were called, the printed out address are the same: the frame holding information to `calculate` is the same. The frame holding information to `add` or `subtract` is the same.

So which one is pop-out in this case?

```
int add(int, int){
    cout<<"address of the add function frame in stack "<<__builtin_frame_address(0)<<endl;
    cout<<"address of the calling function frame in stack "<<__builtin_frame_address(1)<<endl;
}
```

3. I expect the `return address of the function` would be different from the `address of the stack frame that hold the function information when it is called`. But where should they be? Are they in the heap when the function is declared and define?

Here is my whole program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int add (const int a, const int b){
    cout<<"adding "<<a<<" + "<<b<<" = "<<a+b<<endl;
    cout<<"return address of add function "<<__builtin_return_address(0)<<endl;
    cout<<"address of the add function frame in stack "<<__builtin_frame_address(0)<<endl;
    cout<<"address of the calling function frame in stack "<<__builtin_frame_address(1)<<endl;
    return a+b;
}
int subtract (const int a, const int b){
    cout<<"subtract "<<a<<" - "<<b<<" = "<<a-b<<endl;
    cout<<"return address of subtract function "<<__builtin_return_address(0)<<endl;
    cout<<"address of the subtract function frame in stack "<<__builtin_frame_address(0)<<endl;
    cout<<"address of the calling function frame in stack "<<__builtin_frame_address(1)<<endl;
    return a-b;
}


// define function pointer
int (*operationPtr)(const int, const int) = nullptr;
void (*calculatePtr)(const int, const int, const string) = nullptr;

void calculate(const int a, const int b, const string operation){
    cout<<"return address of calculate function: "<<__builtin_return_address(0)<<endl;
    cout<<"address of the calculate function frame in stack "<<__builtin_frame_address(0)<<endl;
    if (operation=="add"){
        // assign function pointer to address of function
        operationPtr = &add;
        // invoke function via function pointer
        // cout<<"operationPtr pointing to add function at address: "<<*operationPtr<<endl;
        printf("operationPtr pointing to add function at address: 0x%08x \n",*operationPtr);
        operationPtr(a,b);
    }
        
    else if (operation == "subtract"){
        operationPtr = &subtract;
        // cout<<"operationPtr pointing to subtract function at address: "<<*operationPtr<<endl;
        printf("operationPtr pointing to subtract function at address: 0x%08x \n",*operationPtr);
        operationPtr(a,b);
    }       
    else
        return;
}

int main(){
    calculatePtr = &calculate; 
    calculatePtr(4,5,"add");
    calculatePtr(10,12, "subtract");
    calculatePtr(34,21, "add");
    calculatePtr(45,6, "subtract");
}
```

The output:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void calculate(int, int, std::string)’:
main.cpp:33:72: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)(int, int)’ [-Wformat=]
   33 |         printf("operationPtr pointing to add function at address: 0x%08x \n",*operationPtr);
      |                                                                     ~~~^
      |                                                                        |
      |                                                                        unsigned int
main.cpp:40:77: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)(int, int)’ [-Wformat=]
   40 |         printf("operationPtr pointing to subtract function at address: 0x%08x \n",*operationPtr);
      |                                                                          ~~~^
      |                                                                             |
      |                                                                             unsigned int
return address of calculate function: 0x55d9f091b737
address of the calculate function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
operationPtr pointing to add function at address: 0xf091b2e9 
adding 4 + 5 = 9
return address of add function 0x55d9f091b66d
address of the add function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918510
address of the calling function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
return address of calculate function: 0x55d9f091b78f
address of the calculate function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
operationPtr pointing to subtract function at address: 0xf091b43c 
subtract 10 - 12 = -2
return address of subtract function 0x55d9f091b6c8
address of the subtract function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918510
address of the calling function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
return address of calculate function: 0x55d9f091b7e7
address of the calculate function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
operationPtr pointing to add function at address: 0xf091b2e9 
adding 34 + 21 = 55
return address of add function 0x55d9f091b66d
address of the add function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918510
address of the calling function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
return address of calculate function: 0x55d9f091b83f
address of the calculate function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
operationPtr pointing to subtract function at address: 0xf091b43c 
subtract 45 - 6 = 39
return address of subtract function 0x55d9f091b6c8
address of the subtract function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918510
address of the calling function frame in stack 0x7ffdda918530
```

Comment: *"the function pointer allows returning to the stack frame that holds the function information"* -- How would this work if the function had never been called? That is, if there is not -- and never was -- a stack frame for the function?

Comment: *"I used `__builtin_frame_address(0)`"* -- Since you seem to be open to compiler-specific approaches, you should mention (and tag) which compiler you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is an `int` so a pointer to `a` is an `int*`.

When you print a pointer you use `ptr` not `*ptr` because `*ptr` prints what the pointer is pointing to.

When you print a pointer using `printf` you use the format specifier `%p`.

Putting all that together

```
int* operationPtr = &a;
printf("operationPtr pointing to add function at address: %p \n", operationPtr);
```

Or getting rid of the unneeded variable

```
printf("'a' in add function at address: %p \n", &a);
```

Comment: Thank you! So the way I print out the value in pointer or address of function is incorrect. 
However, the value printed out by `printf("%p",&add)` is different from the value printed out by `__builtin_return_address(0)` . Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the return address of a function to be similar to the address of a variable in that function. The return address of a function is in the calling function so I don't see any relationship there. But I would expect the address of the topmost frame to be similar, so `__builtin_frame_address(0)` should be close to `&a`.